# Ember CLI Test Helpers

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Can somebody point me to a resource on how to implement a test helper with ember-cli?

Or else a simple explanation?

I know the helpers go in the test/helpers directory, but how do you load them into the integration tests?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I found to do this is:

```
// tests/helpers/controller.js
import Ember from 'ember';

Ember.Test.registerHelper('controller', function (app, name) {
  return app.__container__.lookup('controller:' + name);
});
```

then in my acceptance test:

```
// acceptance/index-test.js
import Ember from 'ember';
// import our helper (this might be done within helpers/start-app.js to always import all helpers)
import '../helpers/controller';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';

// your tests using the helper(s)
```

But there might be some better way of doing.